# ARM Template - Windows Virtual Desktop - Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/hostpools not available in CanadaEast

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Using ARM Template, I am trying to deploy a Virtual Desktop environment in the Canada East region but I get the following error

```
The provided location 'canadaeast' is not available for resource type 
'Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/hostpools'. List of available regions for the resource 
type is 'eastus,eastus2,westus,westus2,northcentralus,southcentralus,westcentralus,centralus'.
```

However, according to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/data-locations), "**Windows Virtual Desktop is currently available for all geographical locations.**"

The ARM Template I am using is this one : https://github.com/Azure/RDS-Templates/tree/master/ARM-wvd-templates/CreateAndProvisionHostPool

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the following documentation, you need to locate your Hostpool within the supported metadata region:

> At the moment, we only support storing metadata in the United States
> (US) Azure geography.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/data-locations

Your VMs however can be added to a different location if you want.

Comment: Yes exactly. It finally worked. The documentation is a little bit confusing about that. You need to understand that hostpool = metadata :-)